# Rock Paper Scissors Prompt To Ask for Decision to run the game

Tags: javascript

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I have been studying JavaScript for about 3 days give or take and I have created a rock paper scissor "game" that runs but only with the player decision is added to the code. I wanted to fix this instead so that an prompt alert pops up to ask "Pick Rock, Paper, Scissor Now" and have the game use that input as the deciding factor to who will win. I have ran the code that I have provided and ended up this error:

```
 a internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'readline-sync'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/zUokdwLcHz.js:1:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

I tried reviewing my spelling and ()/;/, to make sure that they are all correct and I feel like they are. I am sure this is an easy fix so thank you in advance you if you can guide me the correct way.

Here is the code:

```js
const userInput = prompt("What will you shoot")
userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
if (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors') {
  return userInput;

} else {
  console.log("Error!");
}

const ComputerChoice = () => {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
  if (randomNumber === 0) {
    return "rock";
  } else if (randomNumber === 1) {
    return "paper";
  } else {
    return "scissors";
  }
}

const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
    return "Tie, please try again";
  } else if (userChoice === "paper" && computerChoice === "rock") {
    return "Player wins";
  } else if (userChoice === "scissors" && computerChoice === "Paper") {
    return "Player wins";
  } else if (userChoice === "rock" && computerChoice === "scissors") {
    return "Player wins";
  } else if (userChoice === "bomb") {
    return "Player wins"
  } else {
    return "Computer Wins"
  }
}

const playGame = () => {
  const userChoice = getUserChoice('')
  const computerChoice = ComputerChoice()
  console.log("you threw a " + userChoice);
  console.log("The computer threw a " + computerChoice);

  console.log(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice));
}

playGame();
```

Comment: Did you leave out part of the code? `return userInput;` can't be used outside a function.

Comment: You're missing the `getUserChoice()` function. I think the first few lines are supposed to be in that function.

Comment: Error states something about node's module loader not being able to find `readline-sync`, yet the code has nothing remotely close to an import (nor is any loader tagged or mentioned anyways, and there is no cjs in the browser).

Comment: sorry for the delay, 
1. I did not leave out part of the code that is the full code. 
2. I figured it was missing a function how would you add a prompt inside a function is it possible? 
3. While I do not understand everything stated I can infer that the code was showing a big problem? is that correct. 

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

comment out your first return statement -it's illegal and change getUserInput() at the bottom to just userInput

```js
var userInput = prompt("What will you shoot")
userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
if (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors') {
  //return userInput;

} else {
  console.log("Error!");
}

const ComputerChoice = () => {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
  if (randomNumber === 0) {
    return "rock";
  } else if (randomNumber === 1) {
    return "paper";
  } else {
    return "scissors";
  }
}

const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
    return "Tie, please try again";
  } else if (userChoice === "paper" && computerChoice === "rock") {
    return "Player wins";
  } else if (userChoice === "scissors" && computerChoice === "Paper") {
    return "Player wins";
  } else if (userChoice === "rock" && computerChoice === "scissors") {
    return "Player wins";
  } else if (userChoice === "bomb") {
    return "Player wins"
  } else {
    return "Computer Wins"
  }
}

const playGame = () => {
  const userChoice = userInput//getUserChoice('')
  const computerChoice = ComputerChoice()
  console.log("you threw a " + userChoice);
  console.log("The computer threw a " + computerChoice);

  console.log(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice));
}

playGame();
```

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate it. I will be using this to review